# Pass button ID to the controller in AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my webpage I have different cities to select using buttons and i want to retrieve my data from my model based on the button ID. Since i have 400+ records for each city. 
If I click on my button looks like it is not activating my controller method because my ajax call is not happening

my HTML code looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="A"><input   value="A"type="button"  id="btn_a"   onclick="getValues(this)"/> 
        </td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="B"><input value="B"id="btn_b" type="button" onclick="getValues(this)"/> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

myController method

```
public JsonResult updateValues(string site)
{
    list<string> dataList = new list<string>;
    Model m = new Model();
    dataList = m.myData(site);
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string output = jss.Serialize(dataList );
    return Json(dataList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

my Ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValues(siteID) {
        var id = siteID.id,
        var data = id.value,
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("updateValues")',// the method we are calling
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {"data": data},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var k = 0; k < 630; k++) {
                    document.getElementById(k).innerHTML = data[k];
                }       
            }
        });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: in your controller you are getting `site` argument as a `string` but the data that is being sent is a `JOSN` object .

Comment: I need to send a string to my controller from my AJAX call.. can you please help me how to do that.

Comment: What does **ajax call is not happening** means ? Is it having a script error in your page ? Or is it making a call but not getting the expected data ? What is it ?

Comment: When i debug my code.. after button click i dont see my controller method being called

Comment: do you get any network status error once you click ?

Comment: No, I dont see any network error

Comment: put a break point in your controller and see if it hits it

Comment: it hits the controller method but my input parameter is null

Comment: I am able to pass the city value to my controller. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: what was issue by the way...

Comment: The issue is with passing json object instead of data. the other issue was passing var data = id.value to the controller. I directly passed id.value.